# Error when using uppercase named item in raw folder

Tags: java, android

Is there any way how to use uppercase name in raw folder? When I'm use uppercase name, it gets red underlined (as shown on screen).

[image: image of error]

Do anyone know what is solution for this?
Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way how to use uppercase name in raw folder?

No, sorry.

> Do anyone know what is solution for this?

Rename the resource to use lowercase letters. Or, move it out of `res/raw/` and into `assets/`, where you have greater flexibility on filenames.